# Whole content of CheckboxTreeViewer disappears

Tags: java, swt

My sister is implementing some app in Java using Eclipse. She has a control `CheckboxTreeViewer` in a window. Everything works OK when the window appears for the first time (whole parents and childs are visible), **but when it is folded and unfolded a second time the whole content dissappears**.

Here is the `createContents` method :

```
protected void createContents()  {

        shlDetails = new Shell();
        shlDetails.setSize(800, 600);
        shlDetails.setText("Details");
        shlDetails.setBackground(SWTResourceManager.getColor(245, 255, 250));

 treeViewerExample = new CheckboxTreeViewer(shlDetails, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
 Tree treeExample =  treeViewerExample.getTree();

        treeExample.setBounds(10, 10, 659, 204);
        treeExample.setHeaderVisible(true);
        treeExample.setLinesVisible(true);



   TreeViewerColumn treeViewerColumnName = new TreeViewerColumn(treeViewerExample, SWT.NONE);

    TreeColumn trclmnName = treeViewerColumnName.getColumn();
        trclmnName.setText("Operation type");
        trclmnName.setWidth(300);

         TreeItem trtmParent = new TreeItem(treeExample, SWT.NONE);
        trtmParent.setText("FOR ALL");


     TreeItem trtmChild = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild.setText("FOR LANDING");

         TreeItem trtmChild_1 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_1.setText("FOR TAKE-OFF");
        trtmParent.setExpanded(true);

        TreeItem trtmChild_2 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_2.setText("FOR TOUCH AND GO");
        TreeItem trtmChild_3 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_3.setText("FOR PRACTICE LOW APPROACHES");
        TreeItem trtmChild_4 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_4 .setText("FOR TAXIING");
        TreeItem trtmChild_5 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_5.setText("FOR CROSSING");
        TreeItem trtmChild_6 = new TreeItem(trtmParent, SWT.NONE);
        trtmChild_6.setText("FOR AIRSHOW PARTICIPATING ACFT");
}
```

Comment: Please describe the Problem in more Detail. Are there some Exceptions?

Comment: No there are no expceptions -- and this is killing us :D ...I am  I have no clue what can be problem ....alse there is really nothing on the web ...regarding the  CheckboxTreeViewer

Comment: Try to define the bounds and all other stuff of `treeViewerExample` after you added the tree-content

Comment: Doesnt work :( ...It is really interesting that whole content after  folding dissapears .  I expect that createContents() is called at the startUp of window  so  whole conent of checkboxtreeviewver should be created  . BUT somehow it is deleted for second time.... while runtime of window.... or somethink like that ...

Comment: https://scontent-a-ams.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xap1/t31.0-8/10679961_10203042017553565_8863865462819583384_o.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you use a JFace `CheckboxTreeViewer` (or just a `TreeViewer)` you must use a Content Provider (`TreeViewer.setContentProvider`) (and a Label Provider).

Using `TreeItem` will only work with a `Tree` that is not managed by a `TreeViewer`. `TreeViewer` assumes that it has complete control of the tree and will replace any tree items that you add.

So you can create a `Tree` yourself with no `TreeViewer` and add `TreeItem`s. Or you can use `TreeViewer` with a content provider, label provider and a model. But you **cannot** mix the two methods.